# Animate clouds texture for blender sky

Tags: animation, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I added blue color to my world background and then add texture 'clouds'.
I set up options so it looks quite good.

But I'm animating flying jet and these clouds are static. When I move camera & jet clouds are always the same.
How I can easy fix it?

Comment: blender internal render, or cycles?

Comment: blender renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on the node setup. If you go to [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Tr6wTyfAO04) and follow along with what it has to say, then there are specific drivers in the tutorial that will allow your clouds to move and be very flexible.

Here's the .blend file in which you can append from! Just make sure your project is in Cycles, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (append) and go to path\suppliedblend.blend\world\sky.
;)

[image]

EDIT:

Here are some further steps on how to animate the clouds without actually having to watch the tutorial. Now, when going to edit this answer, I realized that my supplied .blend file wasn't actually optimized to have these animate-able  properties. So, It's really quite simple to add that feature. Make an edit to the provided node setup and add a new node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and add a mapping node. (Vector>>Mapping) Put your node in between your **Texture Coordinates** node, and your **Noise Texture** node. That way, the mapping node will have the output of the texture coordinates node going into the input of the mapping node. It's output will then go into the input of the noise texture node. Simple. Once this has been added, to make your clouds move you just need to keyframe the location coordinates parameters. If you hover over one of the sliders and press <kbd>I</kbd> then you will have keyframed your value. Make sure that the other keyframe is far enough away from the first to achieve a realistic effect.

Comment: But this tutorial is for cycles and I'm using internal render :( Can I use this tutorial anyway?

Comment: @Kaki I don't believe that it's possible to make a setup for a sky that is TOO reliable in BI. This is a cycles only tutorial.

Comment: @David Actually, before I knew he was using BI, I actually posted my answer and planned to switch to my other computer with Blender installed and edit it with a .blend example to append from. But, apparently he is using Blender Render. :( Does B.SE save answer drafts? I would have just done a draft if I could rely on that.

Comment: @Kaki would you like me to supply a .blend example file with the contents of the tutorial to append from for future reference? You know, just in case you have this same scenario but with Cycles and want a quick way to get a cool looking sky. Too bad you're using BI instead of Cycles or you'd have your moving clouds in no-time.

Comment: If you can. I think I can switch to cycles - my animations are very simple.

Comment: @Kaki Okay. I'll edit my question. If you don't know, just append from the supplied .blend file in the world folder. Once it's appended, just select the world in your world properties tab. Keep on Blending! ;)

Comment: @Kaki There you go!